# Como limpar o carrinho de compras apos finalizar pedido

Tags: php, html

Criei um carrinho de compras, onde em uma tabela ele lista todos os produtos do banco de dados e conforme o usuario clica em adicionar ele inclui no carrinho (que é uma outra tabela abaixo da lista de produtos, na mesma pagina).

Esta tudo funcionando, porem quando ele finaliza a compra e recarrega a pagina ele mantes os produtos que foram adicionados no carrinho. Gostaria que limpasse o carrinho.

OBS: Estou fazendo tudo na mesma pagina em PHP + Html

Codigo:

```html
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");

if (!isset($_SESSION['listaproduto'])) {
    $_SESSION['listaproduto'] = array();
}
if (isset($_GET['acao'])) {
    if ($_GET['acao'] == 'add') {
        $id = intval($_GET['id']);
        if (!isset($_SESSION['listaproduto'][$id])) {
            $_SESSION['listaproduto'][$id] = 1;
            header("Location: http://localhost:8081/oneschool-master/carrinho.php");
        } else {
            $_SESSION['listaproduto'][$id] += 1;
            header("Location: http://localhost:8081/oneschool-master/carrinho.php");
        }
    }
}
if ($_GET['acao'] == 'del') {
    $id = intval($_GET['id']);
    if (isset($_SESSION['listaproduto'][$id])) {
        unset($_SESSION['listaproduto'][$id]);
        header("Location: http://localhost:8081/oneschool-master/carrinho.php");
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <div class="site-logo mr-auto w-25"><title>ImperialCalçados</title></div>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/icomoon/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/aos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class="site-section bg-image overlay" style="background-image: url('images/vitrini.jpg');">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-8 text-center testimony">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="site-section" id="teachers-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-5 justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-7 mb-5 text-center"  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="">
            <h2 class="section-title">Lista de Produtos</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php
$sql                = "select codigo,descricao,valor from loja.produto order by codigo"; # LIMIT $inicio, $qnt_result_pg";
$resultado_produtos = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>
 <table class="table table-hover" id="tabres">
    <thead>
      <tr bgcolor="#AAAAAA">
        <td>Código</td>
        <td>Descrição</td>
        <td>Valor</td>
        <td>Adicionar</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="lsprodutos">
    <?php
while ($row_produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_produtos)) {
    echo '<tr>
                          <td>' . $row_produto['codigo'] . '</td>
                          <td>' . $row_produto['descricao'] . '</td>
                          <td>' . $row_produto['valor'] . '</td>
                          <td><a href = "carrinhocompras.php?acao=add&id=' . $row_produto['codigo'] . '"><i class="icon-plus"> </i></a></td>
                          
           </tr>';
}
?>
   </tbody>
  </table>
  <hr>
<table class="table table-hover" id="tabcar">
<div class="row mb-5 justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-lg-7 mb-5 text-center"  data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="">
            <h2 class="section-title">Carrinho de Compras</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      <thead>
        <tr  bgcolor="#AAAAAA">
          <td>Codigo</td> 
          <td>Descriçao</td>
          <td>Valor</td>
          <td>Qntd</td>
          <td >Total R$</td> 
          <td>Remover</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
          <form action="?acao=up" method="post">
      <tbody>
          <?php
if (count($_SESSION['listaproduto']) == 0) {
?>
               <div align="center">
                <?php
    echo "<h3><b>Não ha produtos no carrinho</b></h3>";
?>
               </div>
                <?php
} else {
    require("conexao.php");
    foreach ($_SESSION['listaproduto'] as $id => $qtd) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM produto WHERE codigo= '$id'";
        $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
        $ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr);
        
        $codigo    = $ln['codigo'];
        $descricao = $ln['descricao'];
        $valor     = $ln['valor'];
        $total     = $ln['valor'] * $qtd;
        $subTotal += $total;
        echo '<tr>
                          <td>' . $codigo . '</td>
                          <td>' . $descricao . '</td>
                          <td>' . $valor . '</td>
                          <td><input type="text" size="2" name="prod[' . $id . ']" value="' . $qtd . '" /></td>
                          <td>' . $total . '</td>
                          <td><a href="?acao=del&id=' . $id . '"><i class="icon-minus"> </i></a></td>
                        </tr>';
    }
}
?>
     </tbody>
<?php
require("conexao.php");
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $SqlInserirVenda = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into venda(valorTotal) Values('$subTotal')");
    $IdVenda         = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    
    foreach ($_SESSION['listaproduto'] as $ProdInsert => $Qtd):
        $SqlInserirItens = mysqli_query($conn, "Insert into itensvenda(IdVenda,IdProduto,Qtde) Values('$IdVenda','$ProdInsert','$Qtd')");
    endforeach;
    echo "<script>alert('Venda Concluída')</script>";
}
?>
</table>
<div align = "right">
<form action="" enctype ="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <?php
echo '<h3> Total: R$' . number_format($subTotal, 2, ",", ".") . ' </h3>';
?>
     <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Finalizar Pedido" />
</form>  
</div>
<br>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="site-section bg-image overlay" style="background-image: url('images/vitrini.jpg');">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-8 text-center testimony">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="site-section pb-0">
      <div class="future-blobs">
        <div class="blob_2">
          <img src="images/blob_2.svg" alt="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="blob_1">
          <img src="images/blob_1.svg" alt="Image">
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="row pt-5 mt-5 text-center">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="border-top pt-5">
            <p>
        <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
        Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> Imperial Calçados <i class="icon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
      </p>
      <input type="button" value="Inicio" onClick="window.location.href = 'index.php'"style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #CC0000"> 
                <input type="button" value=" Sair  " onCLick="window.location.href = 'sair.php'" style="color: #FFFFFF; background-color: #CC0000"> 
            </div>
          </div>      
        </div>
      </div>
  </div> <!-- .site-wrap -->
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="js/aos.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score -1):

Carlos,

Faça o seguinte, após fazer a inserção no seu banco, verifique se foi feita através de if e limpe a sessão:

```
//$insere será a variável com o true ou false da inserção
if($insere) {
    //Se os dados foram gravados, destroi a sessão e envia para uma página que tu queira
    session_destroy($_SESSION['NomeDaSessao'];
    header('Location: paginadesejada.html');
} else {
    //Caso tenha dado erro na hora da inserção, apresente uma mensagem ou envie para uma página de erro que tu queira.
    echo("Erro");
}
```

Comment: agora alem de não limpar não insere a venda

Comment: Vou Alterar pra ficar mais simples

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que percebi, você utiliza a sessão para salvar os itens no carrinho de compras. Logo, o que você tem de fazer é limpar a sessão após a inserção da venda:

Creio que seja nessa parte que é feito a inclusão da venda no banco de dados:

```
if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
    $SqlInserirVenda = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into venda(valorTotal) Values('$subTotal')");
    $IdVenda         = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    foreach ($_SESSION['listaproduto'] as $ProdInsert => $Qtd):
        $SqlInserirItens = mysqli_query($conn, "Insert into itensvenda(IdVenda,IdProduto,Qtde) Values('$IdVenda','$ProdInsert','$Qtd')");
    endforeach;
    unset($_SESSION['listaproduto']); // Aqui a sessão de lista de produtos é limpa
    echo "<script>alert('Venda Concluída')</script>";
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, ele continua inserindo porem nao destroi a sessao de jeito nenhum